# Can I use SignalR to trigger an AJAX request on all clients?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I have a DIV in a view that must be refreshed when some data changes on the server. **I can't update it regularly using an interval.** The data changes as a result of a user doing something in their client.

In other words: User A clicks a button, and data changes on the server. All users should "immediately" see the change as a DIV in their page gets refreshed.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to realize your feature. But you need to do some changes based on the code.

First, that tutorial provides a sample which looks like a chat room, that means some in his client hit the send button, then other clients will display the newly send message immediately. So I think it really fits your scenario. All codes are provided inside the tutorial page and I show the code where you need to change below.

First, you can change the ChatHub.cs file to add the logic about updating database.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessageToAllAndUpdateData(string user, string message, string state)
        {
            //write some code to update the database here
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message, state);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Then you need to modify the js file which now works like append an `li` element to the page, but you should change it to update the data displayed before.

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message, state) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
    li.textContent = `${user} says ${message} and his state is ${state}`;
    //write code here to modify the data displayed in the page
    document.getElementById("stateInput").value = state;
});
```

[image]